# How to filter selected Rows in AG grid and keep it as selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to filter my AG grid rows based on checkbox selection and I want to keep them as selected.

I know using below method I can filter selected rows but after filtering the rows are losing its selected state.

```
gridOptions.api.setRowData(gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows())
```

I can run `gridoptions.api.selectAll()` but I have to avoid it as I don't want AG grid selection change event to be triggered.

Any Idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? Filter in AG Grid context means applying a Column Filter on the Row Data, so the Grid shows a subset of the data based on the filter. However, it looks like you are setting new row data entirely not filtering.

Comment: By Filtering, I meant to show only selected rows(checked rows).

Comment: i guess it has to do with filter-external https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-external/

Answer (score 1):

Use ag-grid [filter external](https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-external/) to filter columns by hand. In the rowdefintion set the filter for the rows to true.
Override the methods isExternalFilterPresent and doesExternalFilterPass from ag-grid
in HTML

```
  <ag-grid-angular
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [isExternalFilterPresent]="isExternalFilterPresent"
  [doesExternalFilterPass]="doesExternalFilterPass"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

in .ts define outside of your component (or do it static)

```
// Used in isExternalFilterPresent() to detect if (external)filter is active or not
let Gobal_filterSelectedDocuments: boolean;
```

and in your component

```
onToggleDocumentsFilterClick(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    Gobal_filterSelectedDocuments = event.checked;
    // nesseary notification to enable the filter
    this.gridApiObjects.onFilterChanged()
}

isExternalFilterPresent() {
    // Here we have no access to the 'this.' of the component. Use a Global Variable instedt.
    return Gobal_filterSelectedDocuments;
}

doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
    // Show only selected nodes
    return node.isSelected();
}
```

The biggest issue is that the isExternalFilterPresent() has a differnt scope and the this. is an angular object (gridapi?) not the current component. So i needed a gobal/static variable to work around this.